# Uniquely identify instruction in LLVM

Tags: unique, llvm

Is there a way to uniquely identify given instruction in LLVM.
For example, if we have a function and inside this function we have "add" instruction, is there a way to say that this is the same "add" instruction every time we execute it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "execute" it?

- If you execute it in the interpreter (via `lli`), then yes, each LLVM instruction is a unique `Value*`.
- If you compile it down to machine code and execute it, you can use debug info to correlate between the LLVM instruction and the machine code generated from it. It's trickier, but doable. Some complications like multiple machine code instrs generated from the same LLVM instruction, etc.

Comment: Eli, thank you for help. What I had in mind for "executing" is whether on each execution of the same bit code I would be able to get some sort of identifier or other type of unique feature that would hold for a given instruction in every execution of the program. Let's say I have a jump instruction somewhere in my "main". The question is how to tell, in two separate runs, that when I interpret this bit code, I just encountered this particular instruction?

Comment: @Tomek: as the answer says, if interepreting is your thing, then this is easy since the interpreter just sees the `Instruction*`, which should not change between two executions of the same module in the same process.

Comment: Eli, thank you for reply. I'm not 100% sure if I understood correctly - if I execute the same program twice in the same process, addresses stored in the Instruction* pointers should uniquely identify given instruction across the two runs, is it correct? Or maybe you referred to some member in the Instruction class that does the identification? If pointer values can be used to identify instructions, I suspect that this would not work e.g. across machines. Thank you

Comment: @Tomek: yes, the value of `Instruction*` -- note, the pointer, so the address... -- uniquely identifies it, but of course not across machines or processes. For that I'd suggest some form of enumeration (i.e. Kth instruction in Nth basic block of the function).

Comment: Eli, thank you for reply. What you suggest is something that I had in mind too -  to relate instructions to a start of a function that contains them. Thank you a lot for you help.